# Selected as Selected Database value Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

In user edit module have a dropdown in which i show options from database.

Now i select a value from dropdown and want to set it as selected.
SO next time when i edit user i can see which was the last value selected.

When i edit a user i select some value from dropdown, and then save the record back to database. Next time when i open that record i want the option i selected last time to be shown selected.

I tried this :

```
<tr>
    <td>Base INI File</td>
      <?php 

    if(isset($_GET['id'])) 
    { 
    $id=$_GET['id']; 
    btn_edit_file($id); 
    } 
    ?>  
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 


    <td> 
        <select required name="base_ini_id" id="base_ini_id" class="form-control"> 

        <option value="">Select</option> 
        <?php foreach($base as $value) { ?> 
        <option id="emp" class="specialLink" value="<?php echo $value->id;?>"><?php echo $value->base_ini_filename;
          if($value->id == $value->base_ini_filename){echo "selected='selected'";}  ?> </option> 
        <?php } ?> 
        </select> 
    </td> 


    <td> 

    <?php echo btn_edit('customer/upload_ini/edit_ini_custom/'); ?> 
    </td> 


    <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function() { 
                $('#base_ini_id').change(function() { 
                    var id = $("#base_ini_id").val();
                    var url = "/bizrtc/customer/upload_ini/edit_ini_custom/";

                    $("#edit_link").attr("href",url+ id); 
                    $("#edit_link").attr("target","_blank");

                }); 
            }); 
        </script>
     </tr>
```

Comment: This will never work because you are not doing anything with the ternary operator. No echoing or anything, the ternary operator should be in the <option !-- TERNARY OPERATOR HERE --!>

Comment: Yeah it not working but how to make it work @Jordy

Comment: can you explain your question a bit more?

Comment: This is format <option   CONDITION & ATTRIBUTE  > TEXT </option>. You place ">" close symbol in wrong place

Comment: @Rajan  
both the condition values from same $value object like base_ini_filename and id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this :

```
<select required name="base_ini_id" id="base_ini_id" class="form-control"> 

    <option value="">Select</option> 
    <?php foreach($base as $value) 
    { 
      ?> 

    <option id="emp" class="specialLink" value="<?php echo $value->id;?>" 
      <?php if($value->id == $user->base_ini_id){echo "selected";} ?>>
      <?php echo $value->base_ini_filename;?></option>

    <?php } ?> 

    </select>
```

Comment: i did this but did not work please check my code i am updating it

Comment: what is `$value->id` and `$value->base_ini_filename` ? I'm sure the problem is there then.

Comment: $value->id will be the id of that record and $value->base_ini_filename it the option to be selected

Comment: i echoed both values and they seem to be correct to me

Comment: look at your code correctly you are closing the `<option>` tag before the php if condition. The `selected` should be like `<option selected>`

Comment: i have posted my whole code @dray please tell me where i am wrong

Comment: change this `<option id="emp" class="specialLink" value="<?php echo $value->id;?>"><?php echo $value->base_ini_filename;
          if($value->id == $value->base_ini_filename){echo "selected='selected'";}  ?>`  TO this :  `<option id="emp" class="specialLink" value="<?php echo $value->id;?>" 
          if($value->id == $value->base_ini_filename){echo "selected='selected'";}  ?> >`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105100/discussion-between-rajan-and-dray).

Comment: <option id="emp" class="specialLink" value="<?php echo $value->id;?>"><?php echo $value->base_ini_filename; 
if($value->id == $value->base_ini_filename){echo "selected";} ?> </option>
  correct ????

Comment: @msvairam what should i be doing then ?

Comment: both the condition values from $value object like base_ini_filename and id

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
<select required name="base_ini_id" id="base_ini_id" class="form-control"> 
    <option value="">Select</option> 
    <?php foreach($base as $value) { ?> 
            <option id="emp" class="specialLink" value="<?php echo $value->id;?>" <?php if($value->id == $value->base_ini_filename){echo "selected='selected'";} ?> >
                <?php echo $value->base_ini_filename; ?>
            </option> 
    <?php } ?> 
</select>
```

Aside from the incorrect closing tag in HTML, I also would like to note that you might want to double check your condition:

```
if($value->id == $value->base_ini_filename)
```

Seems like you are comparing very different thing

Comment: I think it fails because of your condition. double check if($value->id == $value->base_ini_filename)

Comment: yes you are right i should have been comparing it like this:<?php if($value->id == $user->base_ini_id){echo "selected";} ?>

Answer (score -1):

where is the user saved value ?

first you should get the user saved value into one variable

you option tag should look like below

```
    <option id="emp" class="specialLink" value="<?php echo $value->id;?>">
   <?php
    if($value->id == $usersavedvalue){echo "selected='selected'";}  ?> ><?php echo $value->base_ini_filename; ?> </option>
```

Comment: Attribute must inside the open option tag

Comment: correct, as well as it missed the already saved data `<option id="emp" class="specialLink" value="<?php echo $value->id;?>" <?php if($value->id == $usersavedvalue){echo "selected='selected'";}  ?> >
<?php echo $value->base_ini_filename;`


</option>